# error: initialization with “{…}” expected for aggregate object - c

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

I'm new to c and trying to write a program, and i keep getting this error: "initialization with “{…}” expected for aggregate object".

here's the program:

```
printf("password must be 5 charachters\n");
char password[] = scanf("%s", password);
int PasswordCalculation = strlen(password);
if (PasswordCalculation == 5)
{
    printf("good job!");
}
else
{
    printf("error");
}
getchar();
return 0;
```

i'm getting the error on this line, on the "scanf" function:

```
char password[] = scanf("%s", password);
```

what does the error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: It is not correct as initializer. `char password[5+1]; scanf("%5s", password);`

Comment: Better use `fgets` instead of `scanf`

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for the string and then call `scanf`:

```
   char password[64];
   scanf("%63s", password);
```

Comment: hmm... the code is correct now, I think it might be something in your environment or how you run the program. You use the exact same code as posted?

Comment: sorry not sure then, clean the project and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just learning C, I'll expand on thumbmunkeys answer a bit.

It is generally a good idea to allocate your arrays/strings to be larger than what is required.  Your design requirements may change later.

Also, `%63s` rather than just `%s` ensures that `scanf` will only read 63 characters + 1 for the `null` character that `scanf` automatically places at the end of the array when reading a string.  Otherwise, you'll end up with an overflow problem if someone enters more than 63 characters.

Study up more on `scanf` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).